How to make clang-format break before lambda body but not before lambda
I am having problems to get the following behavior.
clang-format should add a line break right before the body BUT NOT before the whole lambda when it's passed as a parameter to a function.
This worked in clang-format 3.6 but after updating to 14.0 the behavior is different.
I already tried out
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  BeforeLambdaBody: true

But that results in
   call(
     []()
     {
       return 0; 
     })

Using BraceWrapping/BeforeLambdaBody: false does not work, too
   call([]() {
     return 0; 
   })

What I want is this:
   call([]()
        {
          return 0; 
        })

Thanks in advance!

Some related additional parameters used:
BraceWrapping/AfterFunction: true
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: false


I'm often frustrated by configuring clang-format to the layout I prefer.  I've had luck using clang-format configurator v2 to adjust the settings.  I wish I could just edit the source file, and then tell clang-format to extrapolate its settings from that exemplary source file.

@Eljay Yeah, I have played with this but to no avail.
Generally I don't have a problem with this change, but this affects a large code base and I hoped that this is preventable
